# Boost regular expression to exclude Chinese symbols

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to create a regular expression for avoiding match with Chinese characters and in general I want to avoid all the similar languages that use symbols. However, I don't know how to do that. (I cant exclude all chinese letters ! Its easier to include letters from all the other like latin languages).

Is there a convenient way to do that ?

I want to match only words that contain the latin letters plus the hats etc that come from other languages.

Currently I am using the boost libraries with the Unicode support.

Comment: In other words, you're interested in Basic Latin, Latin-1 Supplement, Latin-Extended A, and Latin-Extended B. Possibly also Combining Diacritical Marks. Do you need just letters per se, or all the characters in those blocks (incl. digits, punctuation etc.)? BTW, what's your end goal? Why do you need to do one thing for Vietnamese words (written with latin-based alphabet) and something other for Korean (written in Hangul)?

Comment: I just want to avoid symbols. I am trying to simulate a system. After statistical observation in that system words containing symbols like Chinese symbols never appear so I want to filter them out. In other words I want latin plus accents.

Comment: Ok I have to be honest. Latin extended A and B are perfect for me! I didn't know their existence.